# Pass generic type as a argument in funciton

Tags: typescript, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I'm trying to setup a Crud Service with AWS Datastore to more organize my codebase and be able to switch backends when needed, I'm having a hard time trying to figure out how to pass in the Class type, not a variable, to the function for `Datastore`. What I have now is as follows:

```
import { DataStore } from "@aws-amplify/datastore";

export default class CrudService<T> {
  constructor() {}

  public static async post(data: any): Promise<any> {
    return await DataStore.save(data);
  }

  public static async get(id: string): Promise<any> {
    return await DataStore.query(T, id); // This doesn't work...
  }

  public static async put(data: any): Promise<any> {
    return await DataStore.save(data);
  }

  public static async remove(id: string): Promise<any> {
    return await DataStore.delete(T, id); // This too doesn't work...
  }
}
```

However this works

```
  import { UserModel } from "../models";

  public static async read(id: string): Promise<any> {
    return await DataStore.query(UserModel, id);
  }
```

But I want to make this CrudService to be able to use with any api with its respective model type so that when I want to use it I use it like this:

```
import { IApi } from "../interfaces";
import { UserModel } from "../models";
import { CrudService } from "../services";

export default class UsersAPI extends CrudService<UserModel> implements IApi<UserModel> {  
  public create = async (data: UserModel): Promise<UserModel> => {
    return await UsersAPI.post(data)
    // return await DataStore.save(data);
  };

  public read = async (id: string): Promise<UserModel[]> => {
    return await UsersAPI.get(id);
    // return await DataStore.query(UserModel, id);
  };

  public update = async (data: UserModel): Promise<UserModel> => {
    return await UsersAPI.put(data);
    // return await DataStore.save(data);
  };

  public delete = async (id: string): Promise<any> => {
    return await UsersAPI.remove(id);
    // return await DataStore.delete(UserModel, id);
  };
}
```

Comment: More or less you need to replace any type where you have `UserModel` (or `any` in your first example) with `T`. `T` is a type not a variable so you cannot pass it to a function as a parameter like this `delete(T, id)`

Comment: But i need to use the CrudService for other apis/models right. If I add the type in the Crud Service then I have to make one for every api which defeats the purpose of it.

Comment: Ah ok, now I understand. You want one single instance of the service to handle all kinds of data? Generics won't help you with that.

Comment: How does that DataStore function do it then? If I can pass a class name in to `DataStore.query(UserModel, '123')`, why can't I do the same in my CrudService?

Comment: Does this question really depend on aws-amplify and aws-appsync?  Or is it a TypeScript problem where your use case happens to involve those?  If it's the latter, you might want to make a standalone [mre] without such dependencies and then you have a higher chance of getting help.  I believe the answer here is going to be where you pass in a value of type `new (...args:any)=>T` or maybe `new ()=>T` instead of "`T`" which is not a value. But without a standalone example I can't really tell or advise further.